setting up ubuntu server 22.04 lts wifi
So I am slowly learning to use linux but need some help with setting up this server. It seems this should be simple but as im finding out nothing is. I can not even get connected to my internet.
My router is to far away for my cable so I initially wanted to connect to wifi but could not achieve this. I followed several videos and different form suggestions but I run into problems with the commands not being found and with no internet obviously cannot get them.
I also tried to connect to my other laptop, which is connected by wifi to my router, but again ran into command problems.
I move back onto my boat in a month and would like to leave this pc at home set up as a server that I can access for extra storage and sharing to other ppl.
Ive honestly followed so many different online suggestions today and yesterday I think Ive confused myself a bit. If anyone would help me figure this out so I can learn it properly it would be great.
my specific question to start is how to get connect to my internet with the command set installed.
Here is an example of what I tried:
identify the name of your wireless network interface using ls /sys/class/net
Edited the netplan config in 00-installer-config-wifi.yaml to the following;
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp11s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "access point"
          password: "password"

This is from a one of the form answers I found.
replaced needed info to my own
sudo netplan apply
results;
with this one i get; inconsistent indentation: password: "pw"
with a tick under the p. I understand what that means and try adjusting it to no avail. All other configs have given something simular
I guess another question is this; is it worth setting up ubuntu server for this or can i just use the desktop version?
A longer cable is not really an option at the moment. I did try to take it to the router and hook directly to it via ethernet but still had no connection. I did try a couple guides to set that up to no avail. usually run into a missing command. Some guides used the ifconfig command which is not installed apparently.
re wireless adapter driver:
when i run lshw -C network under wifi config-->driver=iw14965

Netplan YAML files have very specific indentation requirements. Do not use tabs. Use two spaces only. If you provide the entire contents of your YAML file, then perhaps we could give you some specific feedback. Please update/edit your question.

ive been trying to get that to format for like an hour it seems. nothing i do is putting it there as i need it. if i type it the way i want it to look it all formats to one line. if i double space it you get what you see

You need to copy/paste it into the question and format it with the {} button. Since you don’t have internet access on that computer, use an external hard drive to copy/paste it to/from. But again, what you currently have posted is not a compete Netplan config file.

ive typed it out precisely by counting spaces but above is what i get for the final output. sorry i feel kinda stupid right now but cant get this to format

got that figured out so there is the yaml that i put in, found in the form as an answer for this

thank you. one thing figured out. on to the next

In this case, the issue is actually trivial - you're missing a colon in your declaration of wifi network names for the "access point" stanza.  Which is why you have an indentation error because anything after that line is not interpreted as indented items.
This is what you should be using:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp11s0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "access point":
          password: "password"

This should in turn fix the "improper indentation" error.
